# How do I register my application to be the Android default photo viewer?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

My photo viewer application loads a photo file and display it. Now how do I register it as a default  viewer in the Android system?

Meaning for example now if I click on an photo in gallery  it shows show  many app to use , i chose one to display  in the Android system. How do I register my application to be one of them listed?

Must I modify my code to allow this? Currently my application is just loading a photos stored in  the sdcard.

Comment: You need to change your manifest to show that you can catch that intent. I don't know the intent offhand or if there even is one, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, basically, you're going to want to really read through this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html to understand it all, but it's fairly simple in the end.